# duplicate table borders with css

Tags: css, border, css-tables

Is there a way to make the second table borders look the same as the first table?

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}

.top {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  
}

.bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#fin td,
#fin tr {
  padding: 0;
}

#fin tr{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>HTML</td>
          <td>★★★★★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>★★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Javascript</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Node</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>

<br><br><br>


<table id='fin'>
  <tr class='top'><!--
    --><td class='top left'>HTML</td><!--
    --><td class = 'top right'>★★★★★</td><!--
    --><td class='top left'>Javascript</td><!--
    --><td class='top right'>★</td><!--
  --></tr><!--
  --><tr class='bottom'><!--
    --><td class='bottom left'>CSS</td><!--
    --><td class = 'bottom right'>★★</td><!--
    --><td class='bottom left'>Node</td><!--
    --><td class='bottom right'>★</td><!--
  --></tr>

</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would play with pseudo element

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td[class] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px;
}
td[class]::before,
td[class]::after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: var(--t,0) var(--r,0) var(--b,0) var(--l,0);
  pointer-events: none;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: var(--w,0);
}
td[class]::after {
  inset: var(--t,2px) var(--r,2px) var(--b,2px) var(--l,2px);
}
.top-left     {--w: 1px 0 0 1px;--b:-4px;--r:-4px;}
.top-right    {--w: 1px 1px 0 0;--b:-4px;--l:-4px;}
.bottom-left  {--w: 0 0 1px 1px;--t:-4px;--r:-4px;}
.bottom-right {--w: 0 1px 1px 0;--t:-4px;--l:-4px;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>HTML</td>
          <td>★★★★★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>★★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Javascript</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Node</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>

<br><br><br>


<table id='fin'>
  <tr>
    <td class='top-left'>HTML</td>
    <td class='top-right'>★★★★★</td>
    <td class='top-left'>Javascript</td>
    <td class='top-right'>★</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='bottom-left'>CSS</td>
    <td class='bottom-right'>★★</td>
    <td class='bottom-left'>Node</td>
    <td class='bottom-right'>★</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

Comment: Temani, you are truly amazing.

Answer (score -1):

I made some changes to your code, and now they look the same. However, please be aware that I removed the "fin" id from the second table. So I suggest you choose a new ID for that one and start from there.

(I did not touch any of the CSS, essentially I just copied the first table over so they both look the same)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table >
        <tr>
          <td>HTML</td>
          <td>★★★★★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>★★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table >
        <tr>
          <td>Javascript</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Node</td>
          <td>★</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>

<br><br><br>


<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>★★★★★</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>★★</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Javascript</td>
        <td>★</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Node</td>
        <td>★</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</table>
<hr>
<a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well that's definitely better but you changed the borders in the first table.

Answer (score -1):

If you match the structure of your second table to your first it should work. I have added a css class so as to not repeat the border style.

```html
<style>

#borderForTable{
    border:1px solid black
}
#borderForTD{
    border:2px double black
}
</style>


<table id="borderForTable">
    <tr>
      <td id="borderForTD">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>★★★★★</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>CSS</td>
            <td>★★</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td id="borderForTD">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Javascript</td>
            <td>★</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Node</td>
            <td>★</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
  
  <br><br><br>
  
  <table id="borderForTable">
    <tr>
      <td id="borderForTD">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>★★★★★</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>CSS</td>
            <td>★★</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td id="borderForTD">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Javascript</td>
            <td>★</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Node</td>
            <td>★</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <hr>
  <a href="hobbies.html">My Hobbies</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
```

Comment: close, but you changed the original